# glsurfaceview enlarge to the screen width on device rotation

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceview in a fragment, it is working ok.
When I rotate the device I receive onPause, send it to glsurfaceview and remove it from the parent. Before receiving onResume the image is painted in the new orientation, enlarged to fill all screen, for a moment (like a flash), I am sure the render thread is not painting it. When the surface is recreated it starts painting correctly.

Maybe, it could be to do with the rotation animation. Is there a way to deactivate it?

When application is capturing local video it does not happen.

any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When orientation changes, you call  `onSurfaceCreated()` followed by `onSurfaceChanged()`.

Add to Manifest xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        />
```

Or:

You can just add To Manifest xml `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` for your activity